# Firebase hosting Error: Server Error. read ECONNRESET

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

New to Firebase hosting. I deployed few folders containing images to Firebase hosting.

Today I am facing below issue. I have no clue about it. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

ERROR:

```
=== Deploying to 'admob-app-id-4307XXXXXX'...

i  deploying database, hosting
+  database: rules ready to deploy.
i  hosting: preparing public directory for upload...

**Error: Server Error. read ECONNRESET**

C:\Users\NAME\Documents\Projects\Website\firebase>firebase deploy

**Error: HTTP Error: 500, An unknown error occurred. Please contact support.**
```

Snippet from debug log:

```
[debug] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] Command:      C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\bin\firebase deploy
[debug] CLI Version:  3.4.0
[debug] Platform:     win32
[debug] Node Version: v6.10.0
[debug] Time:         Mon Mar 13 2017 14:07:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[debug] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase"]
[debug] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/admob-app-id-XXXXXXXXXX  
 Mon Mar 13 2017 14:07:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[debug] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/admob-app-id-XXXXXXXXXX/tokens  
 Mon Mar 13 2017 14:07:40 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[debug] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 500
[debug] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY
[error] 
[error] Error: HTTP Error: 500, An unknown error occurred. Please contact support.
[debug] Error Context: {
  "body": {
    "error": {
      "code": "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
      "message": "An unknown error occurred. Please contact support."
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "body": {
      "error": {
        "code": "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
        "message": "An unknown error occurred. Please contact support."
      }
    },
    "headers": {
      "server": "nginx",
      "date": "Mon, 13 Mar 2017 08:37:34 GMT",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "content-length": "97",
      "connection": "close",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff"
    },
    "request": {
      "uri": {
        "protocol": "https:",
        "slashes": true,
        "auth": null,
        "host": "admin.firebase.com",
        "port": 443,
        "hostname": "admin.firebase.com",
        "hash": null,
        "search": null,
        "query": null,
        "pathname": "/v1/database/admob-app-id-XXXXXXXXXX/tokens",
        "path": "/v1/database/admob-app-id-XXXXXXXXXX/tokens",
        "href": "https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/admob-app-id-XXXXXXXXXX/tokens"
      },
      "method": "GET"
    }
  }
}
```

Much thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just encountered this issue while deploying to Firebase, the solution is what lead me to this post. After making sure that my internet connection was good, i simply deployed successfully.

Make sure your internet is fine, then redeploy!

GoodLuck!

Answer (score 3):

What's the total size of all those folders.

**Error: Server Error. read ECONNRESET**

looks like network issues. Or maybe you are getting a reset packet after tripping an undocumented limit in Firebase.

Firebase probably uploads a tar or zip of the files. Why don't you try adding half the amount of folders and images at first, and if that works..

ps. I doubt firebase does a diff and only uploads what's NOT there. So you probably can't incrementally add files to get around the limit. All the above method shows you is how much you can get away with before there's a reset.

Comment: Total size of folders is 78 MB. I think that's not to huge for firebase. Alternatively, I removed all folders and kept only 1 folder (~7MB) but still same issue.

Comment: depending on your connection speed, ~7MB could still be too much... I'm thinking here of timeouts from their side. Sorry I can't be more help, but econnreset is what it says unless the error is fake.

Comment: It was due to network issue. Folder size doesn't really matter. Thanks!

Comment: @Shriki - I see this issue on two different deployments. What do you mean by network issue? How did you solve it - kindly share

Comment: @Ram: Using fast internet speed. ECONNRESET was due to slow internet speed.

Answer (score -1):

Try going through a VPN, it worked for me.